# Exporting raw alpha with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, alpha

I need to extract raw alpha from images in order to pass this to an application for use as an opacity mask.  The expected format is 8 byte unsigned ints per pixel.  How can I do this with ImageMagick?  I have tried `convert image.png image.a` but the .a file does not seem to have the correct data.

What is the best way to extract the alpha with ImageMagick?  Ideally, this would work with any input image format that supports alpha or transparency.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ convert -size 16x16 xc:none -draw "stroke black fill red circle 8,8 4,4" circle_on_transparent_bg.png

$ convert circle_on_transparent_bg.png -channel A -separate -depth 8 gray:image_alpha.raw

$ od -t x1 image_alpha.raw 
0000000    00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00 
*
0000040    00  00  00  00  00  01  20  89  be  8a  20  01  00  00  00  00
0000060    00  00  00  00  10  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  12  00  00  00
0000100    00  00  00  13  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  11  00  00
0000120    00  00  01  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  01  00
0000140    00  00  21  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  1f  00
0000160    00  00  8d  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  89  00
0000200    00  00  c0  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  00
0000220    00  00  8b  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  93  00
0000240    00  00  21  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  24  00
0000260    00  00  01  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  01  00
0000300    00  00  00  10  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  11  00  00
0000320    00  00  00  00  12  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  ff  10  00  00  00
0000340    00  00  00  00  00  01  23  91  c4  8e  22  01  00  00  00  00
0000360    00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
0000400
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
convert image.png -channel A -separate image_alpha.png
```

Well, it's quite straightforward: you take alpha channel and save it to another file. Script outputs with 1-channel png (8 byte per pixel).

Comment: This is a good first step but I need a raw data file out of this rather than a PNG.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think, it's possible out of the box. You should write own program using one of the IM ports (http://imagemagick.org/script/api.php): it will extract the alpha channel, writes it to image in memory, iterates through its pixels and writes it to the file in needed format. As an option, consider using BMP - its format is quite simple and mostly consists of raw data.